# Was Herbert Influenced by Eric Frank Russell for the Buddhislamic faith?

Tags: dune, inspiration, religion, frank-herbert, eric-frank-russell

I have occasionally wondered whether Frank Herbert might have been influenced by Eric Frank Russell.

In *The Great Explosion*, reference is made to

> followers of a crank named Kassim who tried to unite Mohammedanism and
>   Buddhism by claiming to be the reincarnation of the Prophet of Allah

It is noted that

> The Moslem world gave them a rough time until they emigrated.

If I remember correctly, *The Great Explosion* was published shortly before *Dune*. Is there any evidence that this notion might have influenced Herbert when he created his *Buddhislamic* and *Zensunni* faiths?